# decompressing with zlib in Java (incorrect header check)

Tags: java, zlib

I try to program (and understand) compression/decompression.
I have a file which is compressed with zlib and I thought that I found the solution to decompress my file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ZLibCompression
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        File compressed = new File("./MyFile.hlb");
        
        decompress(compressed, new File("./MyFile.txt"));
        
    }
    
    public static void decompress(File compressed, File raw)
            throws IOException
    {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(compressed));
             OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(raw))
        {
            copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        }
    }

 private static void copy(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        int length;

        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:106)
    at ZLibCompression.copy(ZLibCompression.java:46)
    at ZLibCompression.decompress(ZLibCompression.java:20)
    at ZLibCompression.main(ZLibCompression.java:11)
```

Then I checked the header of my file and it says:

```
{
 "compression" : {
  "crc32" : 2575274738,
  "decompressed_size" : 9020404,
  "type" : "zlib"
 },
 "encoded_data" : "eNrsvV2Xm0i
```

What is my error? I found a Python script that works fine with the same file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import json
import base64
import zlib

SETLIST_OR_BUNDLE = "MyFile.hlb"

infile = open(SETLIST_OR_BUNDLE)
data = json.load(infile)
infile.close()

keys = list(data.keys())
if 'encoded_data' in keys:
    unz = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(data['encoded_data']))
    setlist_or_bundle = json.loads(unz)
    keys = list(setlist_or_bundle.keys())
    if 'setlists' in keys:
        setlists = setlist_or_bundle['setlists']
    elif 'presets' in keys:
        setlists = [setlist_or_bundle]
    for setlist in setlists:
        keys = list(setlist.keys())
        if 'meta' in keys:
            print()
            print("SETLIST: %s" % (setlist['meta']['name']))
        presets = setlist['presets']
        #print json.dumps(presets, indent=4)
        for preset in presets:
            if 'meta' in list(preset.keys()):
                meta = preset['meta']
                preset_name = meta['name']
                print("  ", preset_name)
```

I think it has something to do with the base64 part and I found a similar question where someone mentioned "you have to decode the Base64 string into a byte array first" - OK fine - Can anyone explain or give me a link to a tutorial?
All I need is the same functionality in Java like the Python script above has - And of course I want to learn something...

Comment: The Python [zlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) says: "zlib — Compression compatible with gzip". So you should try a [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) instead of InflaterInputStream.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to GZIPInputStream and now I get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" - I have tried to decompress the file with winrar and tested different extensions for MyFile like .zip, .rar, .tz etc. all without success. So I don't know what compression format that is. The only hint is the header ("zlib") and the working Python script (base64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your file is not compressed as a whole. Instead, it is a JSON-String containing the actual compressed data as `encoded_data`. You also need to unwrap the JSON-String then. The easiest way to deal with JSON encrypted data is by using a library. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) for some comparisons of different libraries.

Next, as you can see in your python code, the encoded data gets decoded from Base64 before passed through the ZLIB-Decompressor (`zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(data))`)

The java equivalent to un-Base64 a String would be:

```java
Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
```